# Java Authentication over HTTPS

Tags: java, authentication, https

I'm trying to authenticate with a server over HTTPS. I'm having problems with the handshake. I think this is due to the fact that when I go to the URL in my browser, a popup box appears. If I cancel that, I can then go to a form which will allow me to login again. The server security is TAM.

Its actually at the start where I'm having problems. When I try to run this code:

```
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
```

I get an `IOException` error stating that `javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated`. The sample code I'm using is from Apache HTTPClient docs. I've tried to also use the built in java authentication methods, but I get other problems with the handshake, saying the certificate isn't trusted.

Anyway, I'm pretty stuck at the moment, which is frustrating because I thought this type of stuff should be basic enough.

So, could someone be so kind as to direct me to some sample code for authentication over HTTPS?

Thanks.

EDIT:
Just to add another error I get when using the built in java http auth, relating to the certificate:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.g: PKIX path building failed: 
java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is: 
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=XXX Internal Root CA, O=XXX Corporation, C=US is not trusted; internal cause is: 
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is Windows. Or more specifically the WinInet API, apparently.

I can create a custom `TrustManager` that accepts all certs, and it can connect fine. Also, if I try my code without the hack on linux, then it works fine. So whatever way Windows handle the keystore is giving me problems.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing server SSL certificates in jvm keystore, you need to import certificates using keytool. Here is one [link](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/rtrb_sslprobs.html)  on how to do. Here is another [link](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21444700) (even though it is for Gmail, you may find steps useful)

Comment: I've gone to the website with my browser, and found a certificate. I've downloaded it and imported it, using keytool, but its still giving me the same error. I'm getting `certificate chaining error` using the default java method for http auth, and I'm getting `peer not authenticated` using the apache java auth. Any ideas?